# 4 GB limit on FAT32 flash drive

Tags: fat32

I have created an iMovie slide show of about 20GB made up of slides and transitions but no music. Are the individual slides and transitions treated as separate files so it will work on FAT 32 format? Or will it be over the 4GB limit?

Comment: I've never used iMovie, but if you've already created it, you can just look at the size of what's there.  Is it compiled into a single huge file or a collection of individual images?  If no single file is over 4 GB, you're fine.

Comment: If it is a single file it will not work on that file system. But "projects" like this often consist of multiple files and an instruction script that tells how to put them together. Your final output file may have issues.

Comment: Why not use ExFAT on the USB flash drive?

Answer (score 1):

Format the flash drive as exFAT.

FAT32 does not support single large file

No, they wont be separate files and so it wont work with FAT32 if the size is large.